# How to read an Array stored in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

Im storing a NsMutableArray in Nsuserdefaults, I think this can be done and its correct, so Im adding a text from a TexField to the Array but when I try to read it in a NSLOG sends null, heres the code:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *tasks;

NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
    [self.tasks addObject:textField.text];

    NSLog(@"tasks:%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure that `self.tasks` isn't nil in the first place?

Comment: What Im trying to do is to send the text input to the Array, so that array saves the multiple inputs of the textfield, Im putting a value in the addObject:textfield.text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the text to the array BEFORE you save it to defaults

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// make sure self.tasks is initialized
if (!self.tasks) self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new];
// add object first
[self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
// now save array
[standardUserDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];

NSLog(@"tasks:%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]);
```

If this is returning null, then

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it sends null the nslog also with that fix

Comment: Then you probably haven't initialized self.tasks.  See update.

Comment: Thank you a lot men haha I missed it, Im starting so hope you understand, Thanks!

Comment: No problem, everybody's gotta learn! Make sure to accept as an answer if it solved your problem, Good luck!